# JS object composition

Tags: javascript, class, oop, prototype, composition

I have 2 objects **Shape** and **Size**:

```
var Size = function(opts = {}) {
   this.width = opts.width || 0;
   this.height = opts.height || 0;
}

Size.prototype.get = function() {
   return {
      height: this.height, 
      width: this.width
   }
}

Size.prototype.setHeight = function(h) { 
   this.height = h; 
}

Size.prototype.setWidth = function(w) { 
   this.width = w; 
}

var Shape = function(opts = {}) {
  this.size = new Size(opts.size);
}
```

I would like to implement a function **getSize** for my Shape Object. But I dont know what to do with this function.

The first option will be to return the size data (a plain Object) like this:

```
// First implementation
Shape.prototype.getSize = function() {
   return this.size.get();   
}
shape.getSize() // {height: 0, width: 0}
```

---

The second option will be to return the size Object context:

```
// Second implementation
Shape.prototype.getSize = function() {
   return this.size;
}
shape.getSize(); // Size {height: 0, width: 0}` 
shape.getSize().setHeight(5); // I can now manage the size context 
shape.getSize().get();` //{height: 0, width: 0}
```

Is there a convention? Or something more flexible and composable?

Comment: A getter that just returns a property is pretty useless. There's no reason not to write `shape.size.get()` instead of `shape.getSize().get()`. So use the first approach if that is a useful method for you (to be used together with `shape.size.set…`), or omit it completely.

Comment: Why even have `Size.prototype.get`? Why should one have to write `size.get().width` instead of `size.width`?

Comment: I use get() in order to get all public properties, my object can contain other properties, e.g 

`var Size = function(opts) {`
`this._validator = opts.validator;`
   `this.width = opts.width;`
   `this.height = opts.height;`
`}`

Do you think its an antipattern to do so?
Of course I use a simple example, the objects that I handle are more complex

Comment: @Bergi - Yep that's true, I guess it's more intuitive to do so.

Comment: It seems unnecessarily complex. Marking "private" properties by prefixing them with `_` seems good enough, but of course it depends on the context. Having a function returns all "public" properties doesn't prevent people from accessing the "private" ones.

Comment: Yes ofc, this function is useful when I need to serialize data into JSON in order to save it to a document database for example :)  - But you're right it's too complex and not intuitive, that's why I ask the question :p

Answer (score 1):

One should consider all of what @Bergi and @FelixKling already did suggest ...

> A getter that just returns a property is pretty useless. There's no reason not to write shape.size.get() ...

...

> Why even have Size.prototype.get? Why should one have to write size.get().width instead of size.width?

From what I can see from the OP's code, following thoughts are coming to my mind ...

- as for `Size` that makes use of an options/configuration object `opts` and a getter method that returns another object that is `opts` alike ... why not always directly operating a locally scoped `options` state?
- as for the advanced default value assignment of `opts` ... why not entirely making use of class syntax, inheritance **and** composition.

A flexible solution then possibly might look like the following example code ...

```js
class EncapsulatedValue {
    constructor(options = {}) {
        function valueOf() {
            return Object.assign({}, options);
        }
        function toString() {
            return JSON.stringify(options);
        }
        this.valueOf = valueOf;
        this.toString = toString;
    }
}

class Size extends EncapsulatedValue {
    constructor(options = {}) {
        function setWidth(value) {
            return (options.width = value);
        }
        function setHeight(value) {
            return (options.height = value);
        }
        function getWidth() {
            return options.width;
        }
        function getHeight() {
            return options.height;
        }
        options.width = options.width || 0;
        options.height = options.height || 0;

        super(options);

        Object.defineProperty(this, 'width', {
            set: setWidth,
            get: getWidth,
            enumerable: true
        });
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'height', {
            set: setHeight,
            get: getHeight,
            enumerable: true
        });
    }
}

class Shape extends EncapsulatedValue {
    constructor(options = {}) {
        function getSize() {
            return options.size;
        }
        options.size = new Size(options.size);

        super(options);

        Object.defineProperty(this, 'size', {
            get: getSize,
            enumerable: true
        });
    }
    getSizeValue() { // implementation even can be omitted.
        return this.size.valueOf();
    }
}

var shape = (new Shape);

console.log('shape : ', shape);
console.log('shape.size : ', shape.size);

console.log('(shape + "") : ', (shape + ""));
console.log('shape.valueOf() : ', shape.valueOf());

console.log('(shape.size + "") : ', (shape.size + ""));
console.log('shape.size.valueOf() : ', shape.size.valueOf());

console.log('shape.getSizeValue() : ', shape.getSizeValue());

console.log('JSON.stringify(shape) : ', JSON.stringify(shape));
console.log('JSON.stringify(shape.size) : ', JSON.stringify(shape.size));

console.log('(shape instanceof Shape) ? ', (shape instanceof Shape));
console.log('(shape instanceof EncapsulatedValue) ? ', (shape instanceof EncapsulatedValue));

console.log('(shape.size instanceof Size) ? ', (shape.size instanceof Size));
console.log('(shape.size instanceof EncapsulatedValue) ? ', (shape.size instanceof EncapsulatedValue));

console.log('shape.hasOwnProperty("size") ? ', shape.hasOwnProperty("size"));
console.log('shape.hasOwnProperty("getSizeValue") ? ', shape.hasOwnProperty("getSizeValue"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Flexible it might be, but it's still overly complicated :-)

Comment: @Bergi, ... let's say it's complex ;-) ... but since the OP implicitly states that the example code is stripped down, I assume kind of a flexible type system that mostly wraps pure function objects (and also is in need of serialization).